# Remove server side from boilerplate (React) project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux

I have cloned and install https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate project, but I just need client side of project, because I will use another already created server (express).
    This is my package.json

```
<code>


  "scripts": {  enter code here
       "analyze:clean":"rimraf stats.json",
       "preanalyze":"npm run analyze:clean",
       "analyze":"node ./internals/scripts/analyze.js",
       "extract-intl":"node ./internals/scripts/extract-intl.js",
       "npmcheckversion":"node ./internals/scripts/npmcheckversion.js",
       "preinstall":"npm run npmcheckversion",
       "prebuild":"npm run build:clean",
       "build":"cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout",
       "build:clean":"rimraf ./build",
       "start":"cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server",
       "start:tunnel":"cross-env NODE_ENV=development ENABLE_TUNNEL=true node server",
       "start:production":"npm run test && npm run build && npm run start:prod",
       "start:prod":"cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server",
       "presetup":"npm i chalk shelljs"
    }
</code>
```

This is my project structure of files: [enter image description here][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEZuw.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for Package.json. which is for simple CSR React project with webpack, Redux, babel.

```
{
  "name": "startup",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "http://localhost:3000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.7.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-data-components": "^1.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.18",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prettier": "1.19.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

and use this to Configure your webpack add the following code to your new/existing webpack.config.js to run your code for prod-build and dev(localhost).

```
const path = require('path');
const HWP = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
require("@babel/polyfill");
var node_modules_dir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/index.js'],
    output: {
        filename: 'build.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/')
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          // include all types of chunks
          chunks: 'all'
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: node_modules_dir,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {                    
                plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.*css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']

        }, {
            test: /.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ico)$/,
            use: 'file-loader?name=assets/images/[hash].[ext]'
        }, {
            test: /.(woff|woff2|otf|ttf|eot)$/,
            use: 'file-loader?name=assets/fonts/[hash].[ext]'
        }]
    },
    devServer: {
        publicPath: '/',
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
        new HWP({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code: What does it do, how does it work, and how does it solve OPs problem. Code only answers can lead to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), and you risk getting downvotes.

Comment: Okay Sir! Thank you for letting me know. For your kind information, there is nothing big to explain much. I think people with basic knowledge about this stack can understand that configs easily, what i shared.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to start a front end react project from scratch, you can create one using ,`create-react-app` tool.

If yes, just use the tool like this

`yarn create react-app my-app`